# Recitation of vihi noam on tisha bav

Tags: tefilla, minhag, tisha-bav, maariv, motzei-shabbos

Why when tisha bav falls out on motzaei shabbat is vihi noam not recited? Why should tisha bav cause us to not recite vihi noam?

Comment: Please be careful about distinguishing "vihi noam" and "kedusha desidra". Generally they are recited back to back on saturday night, but sometimes only one is omitted, and sometimes both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two answers to the question in Bet Yosef:

1. Because Tish'a beav is a Moed (festival) from some point of view.
2. Because Vihi Noam is linked to the Bet Ha Mikdash's being built and Tish'a Beav is linked to its destruction.

See Bet Yosef OC siman 559:

> ומ"ש שא"א ויהי נועם כך מצאתי במרדכי ישן ונתן טעם משום דמקום שלא נהגו לעשות מלאכה בט"ב אין עושין ותו דאקרי מועד וסמ"ק כתב שהטעם לפי שהוסד על הקמת המשכן ועתה אין לאומרו ביום שנחרב׃
>
> About the custom he (the Tur) wrote (in name of some Geonim) not to recite "vihi noam", I have found in an old "Mordechai" that the reason is because the rule (from fourth chapter of Pesachim) "In regions in which the custom is to avoid to work in Tish'a beav, ... because  **Tish'a beav is called festival**" (we act as we do when there is a Yom Tov after Shabbat).
>
> The Sefer Mitsvot Katan wrote that the verse vihi noam is linked to the building of a bet mikdash, and   **it's not adapted to recite it in the day in which the bet hamikdash was destroyed**  {this last reason is quoted in Mishna Berura sk 7}.

The rule not to say "vihi noam" is stated in Shulchan Aruch sayif 2:

> ואם חל במוצאי שבת, אין אומרים ויהי נועם

Comment: Confirms my thinking! I'm relaying down a part of my previous comment - if TB is considered a Yom Tov, the common minhag is to omit Veyehi Noam on the M. Shabbat before a mid-week Yom Tov. Yet, when TB occurs on Tuesday, e.g. we still say Veyehi Noam on the prior M. Shabbat. Is this inconsistent?

Comment: Re "I have found in an old 'Mordechai' that the reason is": IMO a better translation would be "I have found the same in an old 'Mordechai', which also said that the reason is"