# Vihi Noam at bedtime Shema on Tishah beAv

Tags: tehilim-psalms, tisha-bav, hamapil

Mishneh Torah [Tefilah uVirkat Kohanim 7:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920169/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Seven.htm#v2) mentions *verses of mercy* being read before going to bed. [Shevuot 15b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.15b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) relates that R' Yehoshua ben Levi used to say (at least the [first half](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118043/15256) of) Psalm 91, and the Tur ([Orach Chayim 239](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%98)) lists it among the texts customarily recited after the Hamapil blessing. Most prayer books add one more verse before ([Psalm 90:17](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2690.htm#17)), and repeat the last verse, which is commonly known as *Vihi Noam.* However, [we don't say](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81945/15256) Vihi Noam after the evening prayer on Tishah beAv when it falls on Saturday night (Shulchan Arukh [Orach Chayim 559:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%98_%D7%91)). Shall we then omit it at the bedtime Shema as well?